# Haskell how to call ffi on Windows

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Sorry if this is a bit of newbie question. I am trying to call a C function from Haskell. I am currently using stack on Windows. I started with the following simple example which works well:

```
import Prelude hiding (sin)
 
import Foreign.C -- get the C types
 
-- pure function
foreign import ccall "sin" c_sin :: CDouble -> CDouble

sin :: Double -> Double
sin d = realToFrac (c_sin (realToFrac d))

main = do
    print . sin =<< readLn
```

Then I tried to add another custom `myfunc` function:

```
{-# INCLUDE "myfunction.h" #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import Prelude hiding (sin)
 
import Foreign.C -- get the C types
 
-- pure function
foreign import ccall "sin" c_sin :: CDouble -> CDouble
foreign import ccall "myfunc" c_myfunction :: Double -> Double

sin :: Double -> Double
sin d = realToFrac (c_sin (realToFrac d))

myfunc :: Double -> Double
myfunc d = realToFrac(c_myfunction d)

main = do
   print . sin =<< readLn
   print . myfunc =<< readLn
```

I am getting the following error:

```
src\Main.hs:1:12: warning:
    -#include and INCLUDE pragmas are deprecated: They no longer have any effect
Linking src\Main.exe ...
src\Main.o:fake:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `myfunc'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc.exe' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

I have defined `myfunc` as a regular c function in `myfunction.c` with the correspondinc header `myfunction.h`.

For compiling the app I am using `stack ghc src/Main.hs src/myfunction.c`

All of my sources are located under the `src` directory of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally figured it out and here is the updated code:

```
{-# INCLUDE "myfunction.h" #-}

{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}


import Prelude hiding (sin)
 
import Foreign.C -- get the C types
 
-- pure function
foreign import ccall "sin" c_sin :: CDouble -> CDouble
foreign import ccall "myfunction" c_myfunction :: Double -> Double

sin :: Double -> Double
sin d = realToFrac (c_sin (realToFrac d))

myfunction :: Double -> Double
myfunction d = realToFrac(c_myfunction d)

main = do
  print . sin =<< readLn
  print . myfunction =<< readLn
```

Also you need to make sure to reference your c functions with `c_` in the foreign import directive. So for a c function `foo` it should be referenced as `c_myfoo`. Finally compile using `stack ghc Main.hs myfunction.c`